# Replace YYYY-MM-DD dates in a string with <found date + 5 days> using regex

Tags: python, regex, string, date

**Input**

```
x = "These are the dates 2017-09-23 and 2017-01-03"
```

**Output**

```
These are the dates 2017-09-28 and 2017-01-08
```

---

I was thinking of using re.sub. But apparently re.sub only allows replacement that is independent of the string being searched. So, I can't think of any way to do it.

Comment: What have you tried and where are you having trouble? Please show your code.

Comment: No it's not a duplicate. Problem here is the iteration part.

Comment: @user3682563 Can you show us what you've done _please_?

Comment: What I've done? I was thinking of using re.sub. But apparently re.sub only allows replacement that is independent of the string being searched. So, I can't think of any way to do it.

Comment: Use regex, convert to datetime, use timedelta to add 5 days

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
import re
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dateString = "hello hello 2017-08-13, 2017-09-22"

dates = re.findall('(\d+[-/]\d+[-/]\d+)', dateString)

for d in dates:
    originalDate = d

    newDate = datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d") 
    newDate = newDate + timeDelta(days=5)
    newDate = datetime.strftime(newDate, "%Y-%m-%d")   

    dateString = dateString.replace(originalDate, newDate)
```

Input: `hello hello 2017-08-13, 2017-09-22`

Output: `hello hello 2017-08-18, 2017-09-27`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, as you are supposed to be able to substitute the original date with the new one.

Comment: Ok, I mean it's pretty easy to substitute a string but I will edit my answer.

Comment: Substitute with the assumption that there are N dates, and you don't know where a string could occur.

Comment: @Godron629 This still DOES NOT answer the question. Are you really expecting a str replace call to have the same level of flexibility?

Comment: @user3682563 Note that this is not going to work if you even add a single extra date into the string. Did you even read the solution?

Comment: @user3682563 Even if this answer did solve the problem (which it doesn't by the way), it performs a number of unnecessary steps and operations, is highly inefficient, and daresay misleading to readers.

Answer (score 2):

You're working with dates, so simple arithmetic is not going to be enough. You'll need to extract and convert those strings to `datetime`, and then add days using `timedelta`. You can use `re.sub` with a callback to facilitate this easily.

```
import re
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt

def foo(m):
    date_string = dt.strptime(m.group(0), '%Y-%m-%d')
    return (date_string + datetime.timedelta(days=5).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

x = "These are the dates 2017-09-23 and 2017-01-03"
y = re.sub('\d{4}(?:-\d{2}){2}', foo, x)
print(y)
```

**Output**

```
These are the dates 2017-09-28 and 2017-01-08
```

**Regex**

```
\d{4}          # 4 digits
(?:            # non-capturing group 
 -             # hyphen
\d{2}          # 2 digits
){2}           # group must appear twice
```